# strlen in if else statement not working

Tags: php

i have a array called `$answer`
when i print in using `print_r`
Result is this

```
Array (
    ['answer1'] => 0 
    ['answer2'] => 1
    ['answer3'] => 0
    ['answer4'] => 1
    ['answer5'] => 0
    ['answer6'] => 1
)
```

in if else statement i cant understand the logic

```
if (strlen($answers["amswer1"]) === '1' && strlen($answers["amswer2"]) === '1' && strlen($answers["amswer3"]) === '1' && strlen($answers["amswer4"]) === '1' && strlen($answers["amswer5"]) === '1' && strlen($answers["amswer6"]) === '1') {
     echo 'here i am';
}else{
     print_r($answers);
}
```

but the result is always false..

Comment: wait is that a typo? your `$answer` array indeces has `answer` and you're calling `amswer`

Comment: if your problem is solved, except a answere so this can be closed

Answer (score 2):

check you cheking with wrong keys it's `answer` not `amswer` Also use equals to `==` operator to match else you need to change match conditions (like `'1' to 1` ) or need to change value type of array elements(`like 0 to "0"`) for all

```
if(strlen($answers["answer1"]) == '1' && strlen($answers["answer2"]) == '1' && strlen($answers["answer3"]) == '1' && strlen($answers["answer4"]) == '1' && strlen($answers["answer5"]) == '1' && strlen($answers["answer6"]) == '1') { 
  echo 'here i am';
}else{
   print_r($answers);
}
```

or

```
if (strlen($answers["answer1"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer2"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer3"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer4"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer5"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer6"]) === 1) {
   echo 'here i am';
}
else{
  print_r($answers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*[strlen](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strlen.php)* return length of string i.e of type `integer` and you doing a strict comparison  with a type `string` so it will return false.

```
if (strlen($answers["answer1"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer2"]) === 1 &&            
   strlen($answers["answer3"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer4"]) === 1 && 
   strlen($answers["answer5"]) === 1 && strlen($answers["answer6"]) === 1)
{
   echo 'here i am';
}
else{
  print_r($answers);
}
```

Again you have a **typo** too in your array keys.

Comment: `amswer1` *is* a typo mate!!

Comment: @NoobEditor - Thanks updated but string type is problem too along with typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this line :

```
strlen($answers["amswer1"])
```

use `answer1` instead of `amswer1` in your query!! :)

```
strlen($answers["answer1"])
```

that should do!

Answer (score 0):

you use the === here which is use for equality of type match may be your work can done by == sign in comparision because strlen return int by default so you compare it with string

Answer (score 0):

You Have two mistakes here

1. when you `print_r`  the `$answer` it shows

   `Array ( [answer1] => 0 [answer2] => 1 [answer3] => 0 [answer4] => 1 [answer5] => 0 [answer6] => 1 )`

   but you are using `$answers["amswer1"]) === '1'`

   so in the the key you have spelling mistake `[amswer1]` please correct it `[answer]`.
2. you are using `'==='` its check equality with restriction of data type of value means there is difference between `'1'` and `1`.

   `'1'` denotes character

   `1`    denotes integer

so be careful when using `strlen` function because it returns `integer`.